# Настройка apache+varnish(ubuntu)

Tags: apache, веб-сервер, настройка

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь настроить связку apache + varnish на локальном сервере.
Отредактировал файл /etc/default/varnish установив порт для varnish 80.
Поправил vcl файл /etc/varnish/default.vcl там указал порт 8080.
После для виртуального хоста apache установил порт 8080, и так же в кофиге ports.conf изменил Listen с 80 на 8080(во всех примерах что находил указывали именно так).

После изменений в файле ports.conf сайт недоступен и перестает открываться, если оставляю в ports.conf 80 порт, то сайт открывается, и с порта 8080 перебрасывает на 80, но я так полагаю это не верно и varnish не работает корректно.